# Get Specflow Examples input from External JSON file

Tags: c#, automated-tests, specflow

We use examples or datatables in specflow feature file to give different inputs to scenarios. Is it possible to receive the inputs from JSON file instead of mentioning it in the feature file. Meaning, is it possible to supply inputs to a scenario from external JSON file instead of supplying it from examples?

This is a sample feature file with inputs to scenario supplied from Examples:

```
Scenario Outline: Add two numbers
    Given the first number is <Value1>
    And the second number is <Value2>
    When the two numbers are added
    Then the result should be <Expected result>

Examples:
    | Value1 | Value2 | Expected result |
    | 2      | 3      | 5               |
    | 2      | 5      | 7               |
```

Instead of giving the inputs in Examples, can we give it in an external JSON file like below? If yes, how? Kindly help.

```
[
  {
    "Value1": 2,
    "Value2": 3,
    "Expected result": 5
  },
  {
    "Value1": 2,
    "Value2": 5,
    "Expected result": 7
  }
]
```

Comment: please explain more in detail. what you need

Comment: I need to know a way of accepting input values to scenarios in a feature file from an external JSON file. We usually give different inputs to the scenarios using examples, table or datatable. Instead of these ways, is it possible to supply data to scenarios using JSON? How do we achieve it?

Comment: Any suggestion or information regarding the question is appreciated as I am still stuck with this problem. I tried using specflow.ExternalData and @Datasource tags in the feature. But no luck. It says specflow.extenalData supports only csv and excel files. Please help.